# Catch mysql error in R

Tags: mysql, r

I'am working with r and mysql database and I don't know how catch an insert data into table error in mysql.

I have this:

```
status <- tryCatch({ AnalyzerDb.insert_data_frame(dataset) })
```

But when I run the code I have an error:

```
Error en mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: Duplicate entry '00001002-2014-01-17 00:00:00' for key 'PRIMARY')
```

But when I view the value in status var, the variable has NULL value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`tryCatch` works by *you* defining functions that handle errors and warnings. If you don't supply `tryCatch` with any such handles, nothing will be done.

The documentation has several examples illustrating this, as well as a long description outlining how it works.

Something like this:

```
tryCatch(log("a"),error = function(e) cat("I found an error"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined this function:

```
   myDivideTryCatchInformation <- function(StatusVector, status ) {
      if (class(status) == "try-warning") {
         StatusVector[4] = StatusVector[4] + 1
      } else if (class(status) =="try-error") {
         StatusVector[5] = StatusVector[5] + 1
      } else {
         StatusVector[3] = StatusVector[3] + 1
      }
      return(StatusVector)
    }
```

params: StatusVector: this is a vector with 6 positions: XXX, rows, ok, warnings, errors, XXX

and status is the result of try function.